# How to use modules replace functionality in cloud functions

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions, go-modules

I have a google cloud function that is a subdirectory in a repository. It uses the "Directory with source code" option in the settings menu. I keep getting this error on deploy:

```
Deployment failure:
Build failed: go: parsing /utils/pubsub/go.mod: open /utils/pubsub/go.mod: no such file or directory
go: error loading module requirements
```

I'm assuming that GCF does not upload the entire directory to the instance, but instead only the folder? This breaks the replace functionality of Go modules. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Link to the repo: https://github.com/FreekingDean/jeffbotgo/tree/5d735cc/slackevent

Answer (score 4):

I work at Google and on this product.

Only the directory where you run `gcloud` is uploaded. There is no staging step beyond zipping the current directory and uploading it.

Notably, modules are preferred by the builder over vendor. If there is a `go.mod`, modules will be used. When you upload your function, it only includes the directory with your function at the root, not any directories one level up. So, when there is a `go.mod` and you have a replace directive pointing one level up, it will not work.

The solution for now with this layout is to vendor and not upload the `go.mod`/`go.sum` files. When using `gcloud`, you can create a `.gcloudignore` file to do this for you. See https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/go-runtime#specifying_dependencies for more detail. Alternatively, modify your project to include any necessary helper packages in subdirectories.

Comment: Tyler, should the `replace` directive work with online modules as opposed to local paths? I have a branched module repository, and while I'm waiting on changes to be merged, I'm using `replace` to point to my branch. That works when I build locally, but the Cloud Functions build process isn't respecting it. https://github.com/k0swe/forester-func/blob/a82d4ba67ba4a387c0baf252e3c27b27192f7fd5/go.mod#L30-L31

Comment: Following up to my own comment, "online" `replace`ments must not work the way I thought, because it doesn't work in my CI either.

Comment: I don't _think_ it would work with a GCF deployment. For other situations, a replace is useful when you want to point to a different repo for the same module, like when you create a fork. If you just have a branch you want to depend on and not a fork, you can use `go get the.module@the.branch` and it should just work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today.

When reading thru the documentation for the 8th time i came across a warning box bellow the "Vendor directory" headline.

> Warning: If your project has both a go.mod file and a vendor directory
>   at the root of your project, the vendor directory will be ignored
>   during deployment. You must use a .gcloudignore file to ignore the
>   go.mod file in order to ensure that your vendor directory is used
>   during deployment.

So basically once i added a .gcloudignore file with go.mod (will add go.sum as well) everything worked. So i guess if you have a go.mod file the cloud function will try to fetch dependencies instead of using the ones uploaded in the vendor folder. 
I'm just guessing here tough.